# Read from stdout never returns golang

Tags: go

I am trying to read from the stdoutpipe of an SSH connection. I am able to read it when there is data in the buffer, but when I try to read later after it's empty the read hangs.

Is there a way I can check if there is data in the buffer before reading it? or is something else going on here entirely?

I made a quick example to show what I'm seeing.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

func main() {
    var user = "<user>"
    var passwd = "<password>"
    var ip = "<ip>"

    sshConfig := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User:            user,
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.Password(passwd),
        },
    }

    var conn, _ = ssh.Dial("tcp", ip + ":22", sshConfig)

    var sess, _ = conn.NewSession()

    var stdin, _ = sess.StdinPipe()
    var stdout, _ = sess.StdoutPipe()
    sess.Shell()

    stdin.Write([]byte("ls\n"))

    var numBytes = 1
    var readCount = 0

    for numBytes > 0 {
        fmt.Println("Read count: " + strconv.Itoa(readCount))
        var recvData = make([]byte, 1024)
        numBytes, _ = stdout.Read(recvData)
        fmt.Println(string(recvData[:numBytes]))
        readCount++
    }
}
```

You'll need to update the user, passwd, and ip vars, but after that you should see the program freeze after stdout is empty.

Comment: You're not exiting the shell or closing the connection, why do you expect `stdout.Read` to return?

Comment: When I ran it against my freeNAS machine it reads from it twice then the third time it locks. I expect it to return because it worked twice prior.

Comment: If there's no data, `Read` needs to block until there's something to read. That's how any `io.Reader` typically works.

Comment: Okay, I figured it was something like that. Is there a way to check if it is blocked?

Comment: No, you just block until it returns. What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to use go's SSH package to interact with a switch. I am able to log in, send commands, and read output. I have a function that checks for the prompt in the return data before moving on. I have run into a situation where the prompt isn't seen so I check stdout again to see if there is more data. If there is data in the buffer great, it comes back and I do my check again. If it's empty it freezes and as far as I know there is no way to tell the buffer is empty.

Comment: How are you missing the prompt? It seems that if you never get back to a prompt when you expect there to be one, something has gone wrong and you're not in an expected state, so you should abort.

Comment: I don't disagree, but the problem I'm having is I don't know when to abort as I don't know if I've exhausted stdout.

Comment: I assume the expectation is that you always get back to a prompt after a command. If the command never returns, then you timeout and close the connection. There is never a way to know if you've exhausted stdout, because you never will -- it's an interactive shell that continues until you exit. The only way to can detect a "break" in the output stream, is to detect the same command prompt that you would use for visual indication when running the shell interactively.

Comment: Is there a better/different way to accomplish this? This method worked with telnet reading/writing to the socket.

Comment: Not really if the switch limits you to an interactive shell which isn't intended for scripted access. How did it work in telnet? Reading and writing to a socket has the same implications as through an ssh session (though you do have the benefit of setting deadlines on the individual calls). There's no reason you can't make it work -- you need to figure out why you're not getting to a prompt when you expect, and have some mechanism for timing out.

Comment: With telnet when I read from the socket, if there is nothing there it returns with n = 0 so I know that there was nothing new. With ssh it never returns so I don't know if there is data to read.

Comment: What package is that with? A reader should not return `n == 0` without an error. It's not strictly forbidden, but it's not something that should be relied on, and if it did that in subsequent calls it would cause a busy loop over the Read call.

Comment: It uses the net package. I use the net.Conn to read/write from the socket.

Comment: reading from a `net.Conn` only returns `n == 0` with an `io.EOF`. You should _always_ be checking your errors. It seems the telnet server was closing the connection for some reason at that point. that doesn't change the statements I made above, you need to find the end of the output by reading the output (maybe the prompt changes in some situations?), and you need a way to timeout.

Comment: It seems odd that locks indefinitely. Is there a timeout or something like that I can set for the read?

Comment: Reads are blocking, so I don't know why that seems odd. There nothing stopping you from timing out on your own, either closing the session, or the entire connection if you wish.

Comment: I am admittedly new to Go, but I'm not sure how I can stop when the read function never returns. So even if I had a timer or something going I would never get to the code to check it.  Is there some Go functionality that I don't know of that allows this?

Comment: "goroutines" are pretty fundamental to the language, you can't really work without them, so I would investigate that ASAP. That said, a simple timer setup with `time.AfterFunc` handles this easily and even hides the goroutine from you.